# how to delete record from django?

Tags: python, django

I have looked for alot of forums on how to do it but it just doesnt work, it seems like I could not get the button to link to the views method.
views:

```
    item_id = int(item_id)
    p = Item.objects.get(item_id=item_id)
    p.delete()
    return redirect('viewproducts')
```

viewproducts.html:(only taking the important parts out, also ignore the edit button)

```
                          <tr>
                              <td>{{i.item_id}}</td>
                              <td>{{i.type}}</td>
                              <td>{{i.name}}</td>
                              <td>{{i.price}}</td>
                              <td>{{i.description}}</td>
                              <td>{{i.supplier}}</td>
                              <td>
                                  <button onclick="/edit/{{item}}" type="button" class="btn btn-success">
                                  Edit</button>
                                  <a href="/razer/deleteproducts/{{i.item_id}}" id={{i.item_id}}>
                                  Delete</a>
                              </td>
                              {% endfor %}
```

urls.py:

```
    url('home/', home, name = 'Home Page'),
    url('addmembers/', addmembers, name = 'Add new members'),
    url('addproducts/', addproducts, name = 'Add new products'),
    url('members/', viewmembers, name = 'View all members'),
    url('products/', viewproducts, name = 'View all products'),
    url('deleteproducts/<int:item_id>', deleteproducts)
)
```

all it doesis that it takes me to the same page as products, but with the link as http://127.0.0.1:8000/razer/deleteproducts/000999
Can someone help me please? Want to figure things out.

Comment: That's not what `onclick` does on a button; it's for a Javascript handler. You need to wrap the button in a form with an `action` attribute.

Comment: Please do *not* construct urls yourself, use the `{% url ... %}` template tag.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I already said ignore the edit button..

Comment: Following @WillemVanOnsem advise you should also have a look at the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/urls/) on how to properly name your urls. Perhaps you should have a look at the [deleteview](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#deleteview) too.

Comment: I pretty much copied the format from the data flair tutorial, and I dont want the confirm delete button